# How to constrain type parameter must be an algebraic type (int, float, BigInteger, BigRational, ...)

Tags: f#

-- While there are some questions on the net wrt. type constraints already, I didn't find one that can help me solving my issue. --

Goal: I want to create my own Vector/Matrix types, but so, that the implementation does not lock in to a speicific BigRational (or alike) type. All I'd prefer to require is the standard algebraic operations on such types (+ - * / % equality).

```ml
open System

type Foo<'T> (value: 'T) =
    member inline __.Value : 'T = value

    static member inline Add (a: Foo<'T>) (b: Foo<'T>) =
        Foo<'T>(a.Value + b.Value)

module Foo =
    let inline Create (v) = Foo(v)

    let log (foo: #Foo<_>) =
        printfn "Foo: %s" (foo.Value.ToString())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Foo.log (Foo.Create("hi ho"))
    Foo.log (Foo<int>(31415))
    Foo.log (Foo<float>(3.1415))
    Foo.log (Foo<int>.Add (Foo.Create(3)) (Foo.Create(4)))
    let a = Foo.Create(13)
    let b = Foo.Create(3.1415)
    Foo.log (Foo<int>.Add (a.Value) (a.Value))
    Foo.log (Foo<float>.Add (b.Value) (b.Value))
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I cannot get this tiny example code to compile for more than one single type, such as `Foo<int>` as well as `Foo<float>`. How could I do it right?

Many thanks in advance,
Christian.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it, actually.

In order to create a function that accepts any type that has a `+` operator, this function must have [statically-resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) (SRTP). For this, it must be inline, which your `Add` is so that's ok. However here `Add` is not a generic method: it's a method on the generic type `Foo<'T>`, so it receives its `'T` parameter from it. And a type cannot have SRTP.

A simple fix is to move `Add` from being a method on the type `Foo<'T>` to being a function in the module `Foo`. Then it will become actually generic.

```
open System

type Foo<'T> (value: 'T) =
    member inline __.Value : 'T = value

module Foo =
    let inline Create (v) = Foo(v)

    let inline Add (a: Foo< ^T>) (b: Foo< ^T>) =
        Foo< ^T>(a.Value + b.Value)

    let log (foo: #Foo<_>) =
        printfn "Foo: %s" (foo.Value.ToString())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Foo.log (Foo.Create("hi ho"))
    Foo.log (Foo<int>(31415))
    Foo.log (Foo<float>(3.1415))
    Foo.log (Foo.Add (Foo.Create(3)) (Foo.Create(4)))
    let a = Foo.Create(13)
    let b = Foo.Create(3.1415)
    Foo.log (Foo.Add a a)
    Foo.log (Foo.Add b b)
    0
```

Comment: Hey @Tarmil, many thanks for your response. I tried your solution (by copn'y'npasting into my test project), and it complains with the following errors:

Program.fs(9,16): error FS1113: The value 'Add' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible
(.... and same for `Value` ...)
It is not telling me *why* it is "not sufficiently accessible", sadly. Also, in the end I want to implement ( + ) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is the [`inline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/inline-functions) keyword if you just want to propagate the member constraints of F#'s overloaded arithmetic operators.

```
type Foo<'T> (value : 'T) =
    member __.Value = value
    static member inline (+) (a : Foo<_>, b : Foo<_>) = Foo(a.Value + b.Value)
    // static member
    //   ( + ) : a:Foo< ^a> * b:Foo< ^b> -> Foo< ^c>
    //             when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

Now you can add two `Foo`s of the same type that support a static member `(+)`, `Foo 3 + Foo 4` or `Foo 3.14 + Foo 3.14`, even `Foo(Foo 3) + Foo(Foo 4)`; but not `Foo 3 + Foo 3.14`. You may still instantiate types that do not possess such member.